# Jquery post success and error assign class with backround image

Tags: php, jquery

Hello i got this code :

```
function copy(db) {
    $j(db).each(function(index, db_name) {
        $('#' + db_name + ' td.load').addClass("loader");
        $j.post("/controler/make-backup", { db_name: db_name }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);                
        });
        //console.log(db);
    });
```

This is the sample code of database backup in php. I have use the json_encode to php post errors assing to json array.

I want to read POST success and error event in jQuery and use the addClass (succes and error) with the icons (by css). but i dont know how exacly to do this .

Could anyone help me with using the  .success and .error in this ?

EDIT my actual working code with help of @user972 @Jay Blanchard. I tweak .done and .fail callbacks :

```
function copy(db_names) {
            $j(db_names).each(function (index, db_name) {
                $j('#' + db_name + ' td.load').removeClass("error").removeClass("success").addClass("loader").attr({alt: '', title: ''});
                $j.post("/controler/make-backup", {db_name: db_name}, function (data) {
                })
                        .done(function (data) {
                            var result = $j.parseJSON(data);
                            if (typeof result.success != 'undefined') {
                                $j('#' + db_name + ' td.load').addClass("success").removeClass("loader").attr({alt: result.success, title: result.success});
                            } else if (typeof result.error != 'undefined') {
                                $j('#' + db_name + ' td.load').addClass("error").removeClass("loader").attr({alt: result.error, title: result.error});
                            } else {
                                $j('#' + db_name + ' td.load').addClass("error").removeClass("loader").attr("title", "error");
                            }
                        })
                        .fail(function (data) {
                            $j('#' + db_name + ' td.load').addClass("error").removeClass("loader").attr({alt: "other error", title: "other error"});
                        });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ you should be using the `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()` callback methods as of jQuery 1.8. They're fairly easy to invoke -

```
$j.post("/controler/make-backup", { db_name: db_name }, function(data) {
    console.log(data); // first success                
})
.done(function() {
console.log( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
console.log( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
console.log( "finished" );
});
```

Each of these callback methods can contain the functionality to add or remove classes as you need.

Comment: Post succes work perfect but the .fail event did not work at oall. Che class replace didnt work at all. Could enyone help me with this ?

Comment: If the fail event didn't work then there must not be a failure. Have you watched the request / response in your browser's console?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the question, but are you looking for something like this?

```
var obj =  $j('#' + db_name + ' td.load');
obj.removeClass().addClass("loader");
$j.post("/controler/make-backup", { db_name: db_name })
 .done(function( data ) {
    console.log( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    obj.removeClass().addClass("success");
  })
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
    obj.removeClass().addClass("error");
 });
```

Comment: In console i have the objects (succes, errorr). Because i have the json_encode($backup_result) in php. And i want to use the json success, error objects to change the class ..... But i dont knot how to do it

Comment: You need to use something like : obj.removeClass().addClass("error") , if you want to remove all existing classes and then apply new class. Try to be more specific if you are unable to find the object you want to change class or anything else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use `$.ajax({type:post,....})` instead of `$.post()`.

**Ref:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/**

Code:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/controler/make-backup"",
     type:"POST",
     dataType:"json",
     data:{ "db_name": db_name },
     success:function(data) {
          //process the response on successful response
          },
     error:function() {
          //process the response on un-successful response
          }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function copy(db) {
    $j(db).each(function(index, db_name) {
    $('#' + db_name + ' td.load').addClass("loader");
    $j.post("/controler/make-backup", { db_name: db_name }, function(data,status) {
        if(status=='success'){// a successful ajax call
            if(data.status==TRUE){
                // wrire your addClass effects here.
                $('.classs').html(data.msg1);

            }else{
                // write your failure effects here
            }
        }
    });
    //console.log(db);
});
```

`echo json_encode(array('status'=>true,'msg1'=>'message','msg2'=>'sdsssss'));`
This the array from the ajax php file
`{"status":true,"msg1":"message","msg2":"sdsssss"}`
This is the response from the ajax request